# SCardTransmit() always return 6d00

Tags: iphone, smartcard, smartcard-reader, emv

I'm trying to read name, card number, expiry date etc on Credit Card. but always return `6d00` when call `SCardTransmit`.

I'm using pre-define AID, which i have googled to be valid (correct me if i'm wrong). here's the are :

```
AID_LIST = { 
  "A0000000421010",
  "A0000000422010",
  "A0000000031010",
  "A0000000032010",
  "A0000000041010",
  "A0000000042010",
  "A00000006900",
  "A0000001850002"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: APDU trace required, obviously. `6D00` is INS not supported, so I think you are making a mistake in your `SELECT` command.

Comment: could you elaborate more? what do you mean about `SELECT` command? Don't have that command. my command all start with `SCardxxx`

Comment: SCardxxx are the API-routines to call, SCardTransmit being the one to send a command APDU to the card. The AID alone is no valid APDU however, it has to be wrapped in a Select command APDU (see ISO 7816-4), 00 A4 04 00 [length of AID] [AID itself]. Without some  knowledge concerning 7816-4 (smart card commands) not much progress can be hoped for.

Comment: however, i'm able to get something other than `6D00` when trasnmit `0084000008`

Comment: Good. That means you've got a hardware random number generator at your disposal :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am not familiar with this API you are using, but you will have to send the following sequence of APDU commands:

1. SELECT PSE (for contact card), specified by EMV in Book 1, 11.3. An example is "00A404000E315041592E5359532E444446303100"
2. With the SFI returned, you can read the records to find out the supported AIDs. But, you can do this by "trial and error" using the pre-defineds AID that you specified and call SELECT AID, following the guidelines on Book 1, 12.3.3.
3. You may either call the command "GET PROCESSING OPTIONS" to see what records are available to read or you can read all possible records calling the "READ RECORD" command making a scan of the possible records. In one of those records, you will have the data you are looking for.

Usually in the same record you will have stored the Cardholder name, PAN and Track 2 discretionary data (in which is contained the expiration date).

The tags are listed in Book 3.

Application Primary Account Number (PAN) - 5A
Cardholder name - 5F20
Track 2 Discretionary Data - 9F20

Usefull info about Track 2:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card

A sample of the sequence above:
http://code.google.com/p/javaemvreader/wiki/ExampleOutput

EMV Specs:
http://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223

The possible return codes, such as 61XX, 9000, etc are listed in ISO 7816. Here's a good overview: http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I did try `00A40400` but shows `6d00`. i tried all the example output but all return the same `6d00`. obviously i'm missing something, new at this. Kindly help.

Comment: Edit : I got more, `611c` and `6a82` tried the example output you gave. but i don't see response hex that shows exact same response in the exampleoutput.

Comment: Sorry, I missed something in my answer. The SELECT PSE is actually "00A404000E315041592E5359532E444446303100" (I'm correcting that in the answer);

Answer (score 3):

You need to lookup/buy ISO 7816, the EMV specifications and your vendors card specifications otherwise you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't. could you give a pointer where should i look? is there any tutorial for this? I just wonder how can i read my VISA details.

Comment: Yes, i found none. isn't there have some way to detect these? because I see many people could do this,

Comment: @HelmiB many people have done it, and a lot more, however most will work at a company specialized in smart cards, and most of those don't open source their libs. You should look for universities and research companies when searching, they often take an interest in the security features of such cards.

Comment: The previous comment mentioned Open Source implementations and buying a book, but it had a sarcastic comment that could have been left out.