# issue with get processing options

Tags: payment, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard, emv

I have selected application (`A0000000032010`) on Visa contactless card

and when I issue GPO command:

```
"80A8000002830000"
```

I get error:

```
67 00
```

Does anyone have idea what can be causing this?

Comment: What response did you get to the SELECT APDU (`00A4040007A000000003201000`)?

Comment: @MichaelRoland: This was the response:  `SW=9000 Data=6F518407A0000000032010A546500D5669736120456C656374726F6E5F2D046B61656E8701019F380E9F66049F02069F37045F2A029A039F1101019F120D5669736120456C656374726F6EBF0C059F4D020C0A`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You receive that error code because you are sending an invalid GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command. In response to the application selection, you received the following PDOL:

```
9F38 0E (Processing Options Data Object List (PDOL))
    9F6604 (Terminal Transaction Qualifiers (TTQ))
    9F0206 (Amount, Authorized (Numeric))
    9F3704 (Unpredictable Number)
    5F2A02 (Transaction Currency Code)
    9A03   (Transaction Date)
```

Consequently you have to provide those requested data objects in the PDOL related data you send in your GPO command:

```
80 A8 0000 15 83 13 uuuuuuuu vvvvvvvvvvvv wwwwwwww xxxx yyyyyy 00
```

Where `uuuuuuuu` are the Terminal Transaction Qualifiers (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23591064/2425802) for possible values), `vvvvvvvvvvvv` is the authorized amount, `wwwwwwww` is the unpredictable number, `xxxx` is the transaction currency code and `yyyyyy` is the transaction date. See the EMV (contactless) specifications for payment systems available for free from [EMVCo](http://www.emvco.com/).

Comment: dear Michael, thanks, I will check it, if you can also mention link in your answer to some spec which explains that would be nice. Then, I'd accept it. I am now more busy with the second issue (about RequestCardA problems, it would be more useful for me to solve the second issue :())

Comment: As I've already [told you over a month ago(!)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23113332/2425802), the EMV specifications are freely available from [EMVCo](http://www.emvco.com/).

Comment: Yes but those are all specs, I was interested if you could redirect me specifically to some section. Also in my case I need *contactless* specs. Anyway, thanks.